# How does Civilization 5 interact with other Steam games?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

Civilization 5 utilizes SteamWorks and Steam only allows you to have one thing running at a time.

If I buy a physical copy of Civilization 5, will playing it block me from simultaneously playing a game that I downloaded from Steam on another computer?

Does it matter whether I am playing online?

What if I purchase the game from Steam, will playing it in offline mode allow me to play other Steam games at the same time?

Comment: You can play all the Steam games simultaneously that you want, as long as you do it from one single computer... Although I suppose you could start a game, go into offline mode, then launch steam on your new computer and start the second game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Playing Civ V in offline mode should allow you to play other steam games simultaneously. I feel compelled to point out, however, that steam only allows one copy of itself to run at any given time, so short of some technical tinkering, you're still limited to one game / steam / computer.

<s>I don't think that there is a physical copy of civ V. Everything I've read indicates that its going to be exclusively digitally distributed.</s>

As far as I know, Steamworks is going to function as the game's DRM which means that even if there's a physical install disc, you'll need steam to play it, even in offline mode.

Comment: Really?  I've seen debates about whether there would be a physical deluxe edition, but I haven't seen anything that suggests there would be no physical edition at all.  Seems like they would need something on the shelves for people that are not familiar or comfortable with digital distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure we'll know the specifics until closer to launch, but consider: The Orange Box can be found in stores -- but my roommate discovered that upon opening it, all it contained was an activation code to activate the product for his steam account.

Comment: I haven't heard anything that says digital distribution only. In fact, [there's a $100 special edition you can get](http://kotaku.com/5583378/civilization-v-develops-snazzy-100-edition).

Comment: Fair enough. Verbiage updated. But as far as I know, Steamworks is going to function as the game's DRM which means that even if there's a physical install disc, you'll need steam to play it, even in offline mode.

Comment: That last point is important and answers the other half of my question, you might want to edit it into your answer.